# C# MVC.net - How to pass the id in view form action?

Tags: c#

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.PendingClasses.Count; i++)
{
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[i].ClassID)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[i].ClassName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Remove Class", "AddClass", new { RemoveClassID = Model.PendingClasses[i].ClassID }, null)
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

I can get the correct class id above code with ActionLink. (Example - I want to remove the class id is 6, the RemoveClassID variable can pass the class id is 6.)

---

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Remove", "RemoveClass", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.PendingClasses.Count; i++)
    {
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[i].ClassID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[i].ClassName)
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="RemoveClassID" value="@Model.PendingClasses[i].ClassID" />
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btnRemove">Remove</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
}
```

I can't get the correct class id above code with FormAction. (Example - I want to remove the class id is 6, the RemoveClassID variable can pass the class id is 7.)

Comment: You might have mistaken the number of items with the array count of each item. If you have 7 items in your list or array the 7th item will be item[6] and not item[7]. You're getting the class ID correctly I think.

Comment: Why not get the correct class id same code above and below? (Difference between pass the id with ActionLink or FormAction.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a single form with multiple hidden controls and multiple submit buttons. When a submit button is clicked the entire form is submitted, so the same thing will be sent back to the server whichever button you click. To do what you want to do you will need multiple forms with one submit button per form. The following should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.PendingClasses.Count; i++)
{
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Remove", "RemoveClass", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[i].ClassID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(pc => pc.PendingClasses[i].ClassName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="RemoveClassID" value="@Model.PendingClasses[i].ClassID" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="btnRemove">Remove</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
```

Note I also added a `<tr>` at the start of the form as you seemed to be missing one.